# C# Using Two DataTables in DataGridView without Losing Ability to Update Database

Tags: c#, sql, database, datagridview, datatable

Ok, here's my problem.

I have two tables in my database (SaleInfo and ItemInfo). I need to combine them to populate my DataGridView. At first, I joined the two tables using `LEFT JOIN` in my SQL Select. This worked great and I was able to populate my DataGridView.

However, the point of the program is to EDIT the records of the Database using the DataGridView. Because I'm using the `LEFT JOIN` in my select statement, I can't apply changes to the Database through the DataAdapter.

In reality, only the SaleInfo table will be updated (columns containing records from the ItemInfo table are read-only). However, the ItemInfo table needs to be viewed.

One place online I found the suggestion of having two tables (one for reading and one for updating), but I'm not sure how to go about updating a different table based on the changes to the one populating the datagridview.

```
                                DATAGRIDVIEW                              
                  |  ID  | COL A | COL B | COL C | COL D |        


            SALEINFO                                       ITEMINFO
    |  ID  | COL A | COL B |                       |  ID  | COL C | COL D |
```

In the illustration above, the DataGridView is what I need displayed. As you can see, I need to join the two tables but need SaleInfo to be able to be updated in the database. The ID columns are the same on all three tables.

Any best way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this both tables SALEINFO and ITEMINFO should be leaved as is and will be used during DB update with DataAdapter.
To prepare DataView you will need to create third entity e.g. ViewSaleInfo which will populate public properties required for GridView and will bind them to the appropriate table and column.
ViewSaleInfo will contain two DataRows one from SALEINFO and one from ITEMINFO.
So you will need to wrap each SALEINFO/ITEMINFO DataRow pair with ViewSaleInfo.
Like next:

```
class ViewSaleInfo
{
    ViewSaleInfo(DataRow t1, DataRow t2)
    {
        this.t1 = t1;
        this.t2 = t2;
    }

    public String COL_A
    {
        get
        {
            return t1["COL A"];
        }
        set
        {
            t1["COL A"] = val;
        }
    }

    // and other properties required for view from both data tables
}
```

Using such approach when all work with the view is finished you will have both data tables in actual state.